# Azure - Virtual Network with Virtual Machines - how to do it?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, virtual-network

I am trying to create two VMs, one WS2012 and second Win8.1. I want them to be able to connect to each other through cloud only virtual network.

When I am creating VMs I dont see my virtual network. All their locations(south central US) are same.

This is what I used to create VNet - [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/).

Pretty much keeping everything default except for location.

**UPDATE:**
Turns out it was an issues of subscriptions getting mixed up. I am co-admin on other two subscriptions, and seems like my network and VM were created in different subscriptions hence I could not see my network in the drop down when I was creating the VM.

Comment: why the down vote? This may not be a fancy programming question, but it is very important for what I am trying to do. I have posted questions on MSDN Social but no response in 3 hours. Hoping somebody will bail me out over here at SO.

Comment: by the way, did you immediately realize after asking this question that you needed to redeploy, and open another question asking how to redeploy?

Comment: @Claies that's a different question for which I am yet to find any documentation.

Comment: BTW, I would be really interested to know who are these people who simply down vote without comment. Its like a drive by shooting by some people who don't even have time to say their opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you are creating the VMs using the quick create button instead of using From Gallery.

Navigate New >> Compute >> Virtual Machine >> From Gallery.

Follow the wizard and select your Virtual Network. Deploy both VMs on the same Vnet and you should have direct connectivity.

Comment: In fact, this is stated on the page linked to in the question:  "After you create your virtual network, you can add new VMs to it. It’s important to create the virtual network first, then deploy the VM. After a VM has been deployed, you can’t move it to the virtual network without redeploying it. If you use the Management Portal to create your VMs, the interface to deploy your VM to a virtual network is only available when you select New/ Compute/ Virtual Machine/ From Gallery. "

Comment: Yes, I have done exactly as in that article. Created the VNet and then trying to create VM.